# Flutter custom navigation highlight selected page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm currently building a custom bottom bar for quick navigation.
[image]

I used the Navigation Service described in this [article](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/navigate-without-build-context-in-flutter-using-a-navigation-service/)

Now I want to add highlighting based on which page the user has selected.
I tried to add RouteAware to my BottomNav widget to update the menu when the routing changed but I'm not receiving any events only when starting my app.

```
class _BottomNavState extends State<BottomNav> with RouteAware {
      String _selectedRoute;
      AppRouteObserver _routeObserver;
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _routeObserver = AppRouteObserver();
      }

      @override
      void didChangeDependencies() {
        super.didChangeDependencies();
        _routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        _routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
        super.dispose();
      }

       @override
      void didPush() {
        print('didPush');
      }
```

The Route observer is a simple class:

```
class AppRouteObserver extends RouteObserver<PageRoute> {
  factory AppRouteObserver() => _instance;

  AppRouteObserver._private();

  static final AppRouteObserver _instance = AppRouteObserver._private();
}
```

I'm guessing that it has to with me not using the `Navigator.pushNamed`  but the direct implementation of the Navigation Service.

```
class NavigationService {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  Future<dynamic> navigateTo(String routeName, {var content}) {
    return navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(routeName, arguments: content);
  }

  bool goBack() {
    return navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
  }  
}
```

The reason I created the NavigationService is because I want to show a consistent layout on every page (menubar / bottom bar / background).
Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using any State Management? You can save the index of the Tab and make sure when you navigate to set the correct index.

Comment: I'm doing state management with a couple of providers

Comment: Have you attempted what I suggested, having the index of the Tab be a variable saved on a provider that is used across the app?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by extending the NavigationService with a ChangeNotifier.

Now when the user clicks the button I call a setSelected function and notify the menu items to redraw them self's.

```
setSelected(String newRoute) {
    _showLeading = !checkIsHome(newRoute);
    this._currentRoute = newRoute;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```